# androidで使用可能なcalendarviewライブラリを探しています

Tags: android, android-layout

以下の条件を満たすcalendarViewライブラリを探しています
・maven centralから取得できる
・複数日付に対してハイライトできる

複数日付に対してハイライトできるライブラリはいくつか見つかったのですが、jcenterからしか取得できないものばかりでした、、

Comment: FlutterならおすすめできるけどAndroidはあまり知らない

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com  この会社の製品にあるかもしれません